# Defining part of a string as a constant

Tags: excel, vba

I had my constant string defined as the cell, like this:

```
  Const LID_LIFTED As String = "A19"
```

Everything seemed to be fine, but as I convert batch stuff from PDF to Excel, the rows are shifted slightly therefore the value from A19 finally might fall at A18 or even A16. I came to the conclusion, that better could be to grip my constant value as the string occurrence and then think about the offsets or something.

I don't know how to assign part of the string to my Const value

I tried:

```
  Const LID_LIFTED As String = Like *"Lifted*"
```

I also considered:

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/

```vb
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A100").Find("*lifted*")

Const LID_LIFTED As String = rng1
```

I got an error:

> "Constant expression required"

Another option below:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim String1 As String
String1 = ws.Range("A1:A100").Find(what:="lifted", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

threw error:

> "Object variable or with variable not set"

and the third option:

```vb
Dim txt1 As Long
txt1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*lifted*", Range("A1:A100"), 0)
```

didn't work with the following error:

> "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

How can I include part of the string in my Const value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants must be resolvable at *compile time* - they are not evaluated at *run time*. This means constants need to be a fixed value (or based on some other fixed value), not something which needs code to run before that value can be assigned.

`Find()` returns a `Range` object (or `Nothing` if no match was made), so you can't safely assign the return value to a String

```vb
Const LID_LIFTED As String = "Lifted"
Dim f As Range
'specify a worksheet, and provide all arguments to Find which might affect the outcome...
Set f = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=LID_LIFTED, _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, lookin:=xlValues)
If Not f Is Nothing then
    'do something with f
End If
```

Your last option should work (and does for me), though you likely should specify a specific worksheet for the range to be searched. `WorksheetFunction.Match()` raises a run-time error if no match is made - that's what you're seeing.

Comment: The code seems to be fine, but my last line still throws error:
atSource.Range(f).Copy
    datTarget.Range("H" & lrow1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Method 'Range of object'_Worksheet failed

Comment: Just `f.Copy` since `f` is already a `Range` object

Comment: f.Copy throws error "Object variable of with variable not set". It looks like something is still missing here.

Comment: `If Not f Is Nothing then` should prevent that error, so something else is wrong.  Can you edit your question and add your current code?

Comment: You can see my further steps here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437456/copy-specific-data-from-all-ms-excel-files-in-the-directory-in-correct-order?noredirect=1#comment124512197_70437456